# Quick Launch link pointing nowhere

Tags: wss-3.0, quick-launch

I have a really odd problem. there's a link to a custom list on the Quick Launch which points to nowhere. the content which it is pointing to isn't listed on the "All Items" page, either. How could I get rid of this annoying sticky link. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the navigation on this page:

```
http://<server>/_layouts/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx
```

In WSS3.0 this is under Site Actions > Site Settings > (Look and Feel) Quick Launch

Then, you can [delete the link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/customize-navigation-links-on-the-quick-launch-HA010255192.aspx#BM8).